PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. How can I rewrite a code to place a folder "a" which is in folder "b" to folder "c"
def tdata_move():
    number_of_acc = len([file for file in os.scandir(fr"D:\tdata for accs")])
    for item in range(0, number_of_acc):
        for folder in os.listdir(r"D:\tdata for accs"):
            shutil.copyfile(fr"D:\tdata for accs\{folder}", fr"D:\accs_test\acc{item + 1}")

Error:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\data for accs\\068686868'

So here I'm trying to make a loop, that takes folder "a" which is located in folder "b", and puts it to folder "c".
Looks like that:
acc1 should store "data" folder from folder "D:\data for accs\068686868\data"
acc2 should store "data" folder from folder "D:\data for accs\049193193\data"
acc3 should store "data" folder from folder "D:\data for accs\318418317\data"

But I received:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\data for accs \

So right now it can't read data from 068686868 folder, no permission.

The argument to os.listdir() should be a directory name, not an open file.

You can't use open on a directory. Just do os.listdir(r"D:\tdata for accs")

What is the f in os.listdir(f)?

f = open(r"D:\tdata for accs") Why are you calling open() on a directory?  You can't do that.

shorter len(os.scandir(...)) without for. Or maybe even without range() - for item, src in enumerate(os.scandir(...), 1): shutil.copyfile(src, ...item)

changed code a little bit, still PermissionError

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The permission error is from using copyfile.  Use copytree for directories:
import os
import glob
import shutil

original = 'org'
destination = 'dest'

# Generates paths to directories only with */
for num, item in enumerate(glob.glob(os.path.join(original, '*/')), start=1):
    target = os.path.join(destination, f'acc{num}')
    print(f'Copying {item} to {target}...')
    shutil.copytree(item, target)

Given a directory tree of:
───org
    │   file4.txt
    ├───1
    │       file1.txt
    ├───2
    │       file2.txt
    └───3
            file3.txt

All but file4.txt, which is not in a directory, will be copied to dest:
Copying org\1\ to dest\acc1...
Copying org\2\ to dest\acc2...
Copying org\3\ to dest\acc3...

Ending tree:
├───dest
│   ├───acc1
│   │       file1.txt
│   ├───acc2
│   │       file2.txt
│   └───acc3
│           file3.txt
└───org
    │   file4.txt
    ├───1
    │       file1.txt
    ├───2
    │       file2.txt
    └───3
            file3.txt

Here also is a pathlib version (available in Python 3.4+).  It is a cleaner interface to iterating files and directories:
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

original = Path('org')
destination = Path('dest')

for num, item in enumerate(original.glob('*/'), start=1):
    target = destination / f'acc{num}'
    print(f'Copying {item} to {target}...')
    shutil.copytree(item, target)

